# if we use remove method for remove Null or Empty Values in a list we are getting nullPointerException in apex way?

Tags: apex

When we use remove method to remove **null** or **empty** string from a list, we get `nullPointerException` in apex ?

```
list<string> sList = new list<string>{'sreekanth','Mouni','',null,null,'sunil','sreenu','srihansi'};`

sList.remove(null);

sList.remove(' ');

system.debug('String Values'+sList);
```

Comment: did you got your answer or you have any more question ?

Answer (score 1):

`List` only has one type of [remove](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_remove) method that expects an `Integer` which will remove the numbered index. Attempting to use a number out of bounds is a `ListException`, while using null causes a `NullPointerException`. You can read the line that throws the error as:

```
slist.remove((Integer)null);
```

Depending on what you mean to do, you can remove the null/empty strings plus all duplicates with a simple:

```
Set<String> temp = new Set<String>(sList);
temp.remove(null);
temp.remove(' ');
temp.remove('');
sList = new List<String>(sList);
```

Or, if you want to keep other duplicates:

```
for(Integer i = sList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(String.isBlank(sList[i])) {
    sList.remove(i);
  }
}
```

Note that this list runs in reverse on purpose. If we do the typical loop of counting towards `sList.size()`, then any removals will cause the next element to be skipped.